# How to access API in R with API documentation in PHP?

Tags: php, r, api

I am a complete beginner when it comes to APIs. I would like to access the API of https://foundico.com, I even received a public and a private key, however, the documentation is quite sparse and only provides the code in PHP (can be found here https://foundico.com/developers/)

The code is as follows:

```
$privateKey = 'privateKey';
$publicKey = 'publicKey';

$parameters = array('status' => 'upcoming');
$postData = json_encode($parameters);
$accessKey = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $postData, $privateKey, true));

$ch = curl_init('https://foundico.com/api/v1/icos/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'X-Foundico-Public-Key: '.$publicKey,
    'X-Foundico-Access-Key: '.$accessKey
]);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
```

I would like to access the API in R so that I can directly use the data in my code. How would I translate this into R?

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Rephrased the question, still no idea how to solve this issue, so grateful for any tips